# Where the CGI is engaged in Zend Engine code compiling

Tags: php, compiler-construction, php-internals

I am trying to get deeper in the zend engine and the whole server processes at all
and from what I understood is - when I send a request to the server, the Zend Engine first engages the `scanning\lexing` process which converts the plain-text to tokens. After that the `parser` converts these tokens to expressions. 3th step is convert the expressions in bytecode by the `compiler`. In the end the `virtual cpu` outputs the result. Where should the CGI engage in this scenario ? After ton of articles I am pretty much lost in the whole process. Thank you in advance!

Comment: CGI? As in Common Gateway Interface? Why would you use CGI in 2018 for anything, let alone for PHP (where you have options like mod_php and FastCGI)?

Comment: Just want to start from the "basics". I know there is FastCGI already :)

Comment: CGI is how the server talks to PHP (or whatever other executable you have). Everything you described happens inside PHP.

Comment: Well, that throws some clarity. Thank you!